# Cant get test outcomes with an Azure Devops query

Tags: azure-devops

I need to get a table of test case results using a query. I have many test cases which are children to many parent test suites. Each test case is tagged, so i am able to get them all in one query, regardless of their parent suite.

I have two issues -
- I cannot return the outcome/result of each test case
- I cannot include a column which identifies the parent suite name to which this test case belongs.

In summary i need to be able to perform tag driven test case outcome reporting, and have full control over the columns to be pulled 
e.g. parent suite name, outcome, date run, build version (custom fields).

Am i missing something as this does not seem to be a feature of Azure Devops which seems like something that should be fundamentally available. Quick and easy to configure human readable dynamic test results reporting bolted onto the Test Plan functionality Azure Devops already provides.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that your idea of using the query to get the test outcomes is impossible.
The content you can query through the azure devops query is defined in the Column options. But, there is no test outcomes defined in the Column, so it is impossible to query this result.

To get test case results,you could try to use this [rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0).

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/{runId}/results?api-version=5.0
```

I use this api in the post man and successfully get a list of test results.
[image]

Comment: Thanks.I saw it is possible to use rest APIs, but its a long winded way of reporting. It seems there is some helpful functionality MS are missing from the front end here.
I want to be able to filter across the top level to pull out cases, list a snapshot  summary table. Fundamentally, a cumulative pass:fail:active:etc ratio is the goal here.

Is there a method you are aware for raising this direct to MS?

Thanks!

Comment: @Rich I'm afraid there's no simpler way.